# jquery email site url via email form

Tags: jquery, forms, email

Is there a way to make a very simple form with jquery where a person can enter the email address of a person, enter their name and it sends an e-mail to the e-mail address they entered with a simple message like "Blank thought you'd be interested in this link" and the link of the page?  I've been having a hard time finding info on this.

Comment: Not in JQuery itself - I think that most of us would use a little bit of PHP or Perl on the server to handle the mail and JQuery to manage the link between page and script

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email "only" using jquery, You have to consider php etc. But as you only want to use jquery, there is one pretty easy solution.

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>Email:
      <input type="text" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>Content:
      <input type="text" name="comment">
      </p>

      <input type="submit" value="Send" class='submit'>
</form>
```

Then use jquery to change action field,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('click', '.submit', function() {
        var mail = $("input[name='email']").val();
        $('form').attr('action',"mailto:" + mail);
    });
})
```

Comment: so is it possible to do this in such a way where it doesn't open the mail client on your computer, and just sends the email off when you hit send?

Comment: @loriensleafs, no it's not possible. You have to use php or perl to do so.